# Capture failed routes in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have

`Route::get('/layouttest/{category}/{brand}', 
    array('as' => 'main', 'uses' => 'MainController@showUrls'))
    ->where(array('category' => '[0-9]+', 'brand' => '[0-9]+'));`

Which works fine. But I want a route to capture other get requests to `/layouttest/`. Such as when `{category}` and `{brand}` fail the `->where` condition, or when they're not both provided. I can't even get this to work, (I have placed if after the above route in routes.php because):

```
Route::get('/layouttest/', 
    array('as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'MainController@index'));
```

When I request `/layouttest/` I get a `NotFoundHttpException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
Route::get('/layouttest/{category?}/{brand?}', array('as' => 'main', 'uses' => 'MainController@showUrls'))->where(array('category' => '[0-9]+', 'brand' => '[0-9]+'));
```

You'll need to create two routes to fallback to another controllers:

```
Route::get('/layouttest/{category}/{brand}', array('as' => 'main', 'uses' => 'MainController@showUrls'))->where(array('category' => '[0-9]+', 'brand' => '[0-9]+'));

Route::get('/layouttest/{category?}/{brand?}', array('as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'AnotherController@showUrls'));
```

As long as you keep this one in second place, you're good.

Comment: Thanks, I considered using optional parameters, but what if I want to route to a different controller if category and brand aren't both present?

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution that worked for me eventually. The problem I had is that it doesn't work when routes are named the same (I was using the same controller for both routes but with different methods) I changed the 'as' => 'main' of the second route to 'as' => 'index' now it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to change the route name and it matters.